# Is any way to create one servlet with two url-path?

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee

I want to run my webApp with two differenc URL-paths like:
localhost:8080/firstURL
localhost:8080/secURL

FirstURL and secURL should display the same start view. 
What should I impleneted that by using ?

```
<module-name>firstURL</module-name>
<display-name>name</display-name>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do the following in your `web.xml`:

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/foo</url-pattern>
   <url-pattern>/bar</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

With annotations, you would have:

```java
@WebServlet({"/foo", "/bar"})
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    ...
}
```